# parsing NSString data-getting null value

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsdictionary, nsdata, nsjsonserialization

I am parsing and `NSString` value but getting `null` in console. Please help me with the issue.

```
NSString *responseData = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:_responseData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSLog(@"Data: %@", responseData);
NSData *data = [responseData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

id json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
NSDictionary *res = [json objectForKey:@"demo"];
NSLog(@"res is %@",res);
```

Comment: Could you show the logs? Is the encoding correct?

Comment: Where are you having the issue? converting `_responseData` to string or deserialising data to a JSON object?

Comment: This is your problem:  `error:nil`.  How do you ever expect to debug anything if you ignore errors?

Comment: And you shouldn't use ASCII encoding at all for JSON (always UTF) and you shouldn't translate from NSData to NSString and back to NSData -- just pass the input NSData to NSJSONSerialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having a similar problem in one of my projects. I was trying to create NSString from NSData(response from webservice) and i was getting a nil. I found out that using NSASCIIStringEncoding when creating the String solved my problem. It turns out that even though UTF8 has all ASCII chars, char * may not line up correctly for certain characters and by default the init methods do nonlossy encoding which means that nil gets returned when an unexpected char is encountered.
For your case this could be your code.

```
NSString *responseData = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:_responseData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSLog(@"Data: %@", responseData);
NSData *data = [responseData dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
id json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
NSDictionary *res = [json objectForKey:@"demo"];
NSLog(@"res is %@",res);
```

NOTE: I am not sure why you are doing all the _responseData->data conversion. If you are doing that just to deserialize your _responseData to json object, you could use it directly in NSJSONSerialization. As below.

```
id json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:_responseData options:0 error:nil];
```

For more information check out this [link](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/122983-nsstring-initwithdata-nsutf8stringencoding-returns-nil.html).

Comment: not working dude,thanks for your effort,i think there is a problem with backend.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe error appear because you using different encoding? Try using NSUTF8StringEncoding in NSString and in NSData.

Answer (score 0):

From NSString [class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/initWithData%3aencoding%3a):

`-initWithData:encoding:`

> **Return Value**
>   An NSString object initialized by converting the bytes in data into Unicode characters using encoding. The returned
>   object may be different from the original receiver. Returns nil if the
>   initialization fails for some reason **(for example if data does not
>   represent valid data for encoding)**.

Where are you getting `_responseData` from? Is it definitely an `NSData`object?
Are you sure that you are using the correct encoding?

Could you print out `_responseData` and update your question so we can take a look?

Comment: am getting _responseData in  - (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection.

Comment: You are not being clear enough as to what your issue is. Are you correctly appending the data as it comes in on `connection:didReceiveData:`?

Comment: am getting the value from backend and storing in NSString,here data showing in console area,but while parsing that nsstring gettinh null value

Comment: yea [_responseData appendData:data];

Comment: sorry,data is confidential.

Comment: You're making it really difficult to help then unfortunately. I'd suggest trying to covert the hex representation of the data in log output to a string via an online tool or hex editor to see if it is what you are expecting.

Comment: but am not only getting the json format alone,some other kinda php data is also available there.